# 'NoneType' object has no attribute in Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a function in models, and its giving me this error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'`, please check my code and please let me know where i am mistaking.
i have the relation between `product` and `orderitem` table

here is my `models.py` file...

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=225)
    slug=models.SlugField(max_length=225, unique=True)
    totalprice=models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    @property
    def get_total(self):
        total = self.product.price * self.quantity
        return total
```

here is my `list.html` file...

```
 {% for item in items %}
  <div class="media-body">
     <a href="javascript:void()">
      <h4>{{item.product.name}}</h4>
     </a>
      <h4><span>{{item.quantity}}</span></h4>
      <h4><span>$ {{item.get_total}}</span></h4>
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: your OrderItem does not have related Product set (self.product.price fails)

Comment: some `product_id` are `Null` in `orderitem` table, how i can stop Null insertion